# Changes in css code aren't showing up when I "inspect element"

Tags: html, css, styles, whitespace, padding

I'm trying to remove unnecessary and unappealing white space from my website. The main source of these whitespace was padding in #main which I removed.

```
 #main
{
    padding: 0em 0 0em 0;
}
```

However, after I upload my changes to my server, the white spaces remain. When I go to "inspect element" #main, the original code (shown below) is what comes up, even though 'm positive that the changes above were sent and saved to my server.

```
 #main
{
    padding: 6em 0 6em 0;
}
```

What is the source of this discrepancy? Any help is GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your local and server caches?

Comment: CTRL + F5 the page and check again, alternatively by using Developer Tools of some sort (Chrome/Firefox) check if the proper css file is being loaded.

Comment: It's a cache problem, either browser or server, to avoid the browser caching you can use the equivalent of chrome incognito mode. Server caching is another beast entirely and you need to go through and config this yourself.

Comment: To fix the immediate problem provided the CSS is externally linked you can just change the name of the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that I do when I get caching problems..

View the file directly eg; `mysite.com/style.css` and see if the file is old or new, from experience this will also recache the file in Chrome and Safari - sometimes not in FF and not sure about IE.

If it's a php file which is requesting the css file try adding

```
<link type="text/css" href="style.css?<?php echo rand();?>">
```

This will append a random number to the file, eg; `style.css?2345` which still links to the same file but with a different name, causing it to recache every visit. Take this off in production though, obviously.